# How to change a files signature

Tags: hash, digital-signature, signing

How can I manipulate a file so that the MD5/SHA1 signature is altered. I would like to do it in a generic way, without knowing the file type, exe, pdf, jpg etc. Is it possibly to do like this and not corrupt the file?

I'm not trying to construct a new known signature just change from the existing one. I don't care what the new signature is.

I had been thinking about just adding a new null byte to the end of the file. Would that break any format?

Answer (score 1):

Binary formats specify the format in bits. So it depends on the format what each bit means. In other words: you cannot change the file without understanding the format if you want it to remain valid. Adding a zero byte may work for many formats as it may be simply ignored, but this is not a given.

Alternatively you could lookup locations in existing formats and store them in a table. You can usually lookup the format using the `file` command in Posix systems (Linux, CygWin...).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Maarten. It depends on the file format, so you need a map of rules per format.
I would try though adding a ZERO byte at the end of the file. It may work in the majority of common files.

```
    RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("filePath", "r");
    byte[] b = new byte[(int)f.length() + 1];
    f.read(b);


    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("newFilePath");
    fos.write(b);
```